# Cambiar idioma de página web usando cookies

Tags: php, web, cookies

No estoy seguro de que estoy haciendo mal, espero que me podáis ayudar...
En el index.php de la url base tengo esto:

```
<?php
        if( isset( $_COOKIE['lang']) )
        {
            //Actualizar cookie
            setcookie("lang", $_COOKIE['lang'], time() + (6000), "/");
        }
        else
        {
            //Valor por defecto
            setcookie("lang", 'esp', time() + (6000),"/" );
        }
?>
```

Tengo un subdirectorio para cada idioma, ESP and ENG.
En la cabecera principal que es incluida en todos los archivos de cada idioma, vuelvo a actualizar la cookie según la url/directorio en el que esté.

El problema es que cada vez que vuelvo a la url base, que me tiene que redirigir según el valor de la cookie, siempre me envia a la de esp, ignorando la actualización a eng de la cookie.

En los subdirectorios de cada idioma (este ejemplo es el de eng), actualizo la cookie así:

```
setcookie("lang", 'eng', time() + (6000), "/");
```

también he probado con:

```
setcookie("lang", 'eng', time() + (6000), "../");
```

Pero nada.
Seguro que es algo estúpido, pero es mi primera vez intentando esto, y no he encontrado mucho más que me pueda guiar sobre que estoy haciendo mal con las cookies.
Gracias!

Comment: You're at so en español so please translate your question into spanish, otherwise it will be closed

Comment: @BetaM Hecho, gracias : )